# PDF reader that functions within asymmetrical dual monitor configuration

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, pdf

My laptop is 40% of my typical reading surface -- with the other 60% being a larger, desk-bound monitor.  Adobe Reader fails to use the entire size of the larger monitor -- cropping the PDF to about 2/3 the potential size.  Sumatra PDF Reader avoids this problem, but Sumatra doesn't let me cut and paste from my PDFs.  Is there a configuration or a PDF reader that lets me both a) fully enlarge the PDF to fill the larger screen and b) copy text found therein?

I'm using the nVidia graphics chipset in the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evince works fine here, but I run Linux with an Intel chip.